# SQL query to filter by specific date criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL query to filter by specific date criteria

SQL Server Management Studio V17.7

Question: I am looking for guidance related to a view on how to select records where the Start_Date falls between a defined date range when either the Admit_Status = 1 or Admit_Status = 0 as shown below:

Criteria should be something like: if admit status = 1 then dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT.START_DATE  >= referral_date to ifnull dbo.PT_ADMISSION.TERMINATION_DATE  then now() else dbo.PT_ADMISSION.TERMINATION_DATE  or if admit status = 0 then start_date >= referral_date to ifnull dbo.PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_TERM_DATE then now() else dbo.PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_TERM_DATE

My SQL query (View) excluding the above question:

```
SELECT dbo.RES_BASIC.RESOURCE_ID,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.ADMISSION_ID,
    dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT.START_DATE,
    (CASE PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_ADMIT_DATE WHEN NULL THEN PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE ELSE PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_ADMIT_DATE END) AS REFERRAL_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_ADMIT_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_TERM_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.TERMINATION_DATE,
    CASE WHEN PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ADMIT_STATUS,
    dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE,
    dbo.RES_BASIC.NAME_FULL
FROM dbo.PT_BASIC
INNER JOIN dbo.PT_STATUS
    ON dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID = dbo.PT_STATUS.PATIENT_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.A_PATIENT_STATUS
    ON dbo.PT_STATUS.ADMIN_SET_ID = dbo.A_PATIENT_STATUS.ADMIN_SET_ID
        AND dbo.PT_STATUS.STATUS_CODE = dbo.A_PATIENT_STATUS.STATUS_CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.O_DATASET
    ON dbo.PT_BASIC.DATASET_ID = dbo.O_DATASET.DATASET_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.PT_ADMISSION
    ON dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID = dbo.PT_ADMISSION.PATIENT_ID
        AND dbo.PT_STATUS.ADMISSION_ID = dbo.PT_ADMISSION.ADMISSION_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT
    ON dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID = dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT.PATIENT_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE
    ON dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT.ADMIN_SET_ID = dbo.A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.ADMIN_SET_ID
        AND dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = dbo.A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.RES_BASIC
    ON dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT.RESOURCE_ID = dbo.RES_BASIC.RESOURCE_ID
WHERE (dbo.O_DATASET.DATASET_NAME = 'XXXXXXXXXX')
    AND (dbo.A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'REFERRING PHYSICIAN')
GROUP BY dbo.RES_BASIC.NAME_FIRST + ' ' + dbo.RES_BASIC.NAME_LAST,
    dbo.RES_BASIC.RESOURCE_ID,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.ADMISSION_ID,
    dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE,
    dbo.PT_ASSIGNMENT.START_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_TERM_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.PROSPECT_ADMIT_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.TERMINATION_DATE,
    dbo.PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE,
    dbo.RES_BASIC.NAME_FULL
```

Comment: SAmple data and desired results (minimal necessary to recreate logic) would be very helpful here as your wall of `if` logic is very difficult to parse and it's not clear from your sql how to reverse engineer what you are after.

Comment: MySQL != MS SQL Server

Comment: @Uueerdo I adjusted the tags. Good catch!

Comment: You really need to start using aliases. 3 and 4 part column name references have been deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017 Not to mention is saves tons of typing and makes your code a lot more legible.

Answer (score 1):

You can put pretty much any "if" into a condition with simple AND and OR use.

I am having a hard time mentally parsing your "something like" portion, but to give a generic example.

`IF A THEN B ELSE C`

can be translated to `(A AND B) OR (NOT A AND C)`

Note: Bill Braskey's "comment" is also worth considering. If the conditional logic gets complicated enough, it can be less work for the database to UNION queries with simpler conditions. You'd still need the condition in one to be `A AND B` and the other to be `NOT A AND C` to apply the conditions appropriately, but you'd be simplifying from the overall condition (especially when you consider "C" could actually be a translation of `IF D THEN E ELSE F`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just take the easy way out and write two queries with the separate requirements and do a union

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer. Once you get enough rep you can leave comments.